# Sahih al-Bukhari 3175 contradiction?

Tags: quran, hadith

Once the Prophet (ﷺ) was bewitched so that he began to imagine that he had done a thing which in fact he had not done.
Sahih al-Bukhari 3175

Quran 15:42
“Indeed, My servants - no authority will you have over them, except those who follow you of the deviators.”

(In the previous verse Allah was talking to Iblees)

I think I found a contradiction. Please someone clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a contradiction as the Quranic verse is about following satan's influence and committing sins, it is a response to his statement:

> #### قال رب بما أغويتني لأزينن لهم في الأرض ولأغوينهم أجمعين
>
> [Iblees] said, "My Lord, because You have put me in error, I will surely make [disobedience] attractive to them on earth, and I will mislead them all
>
> <sup>— [Quran 15:39](http://quran.com/15/39)</sup>

The verse is not about being immune to harm by satan or his servants. Scholars say that Allah permitted for the prophet to suffer the harm of magic so that his status would be elevated because of the virtues he earned from his patience and so that the Muslims would learn from him.